# Merging dataframes on index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes and each one has two index columns. I would like to merge them. For example, the first dataframe is the following:

```
                   V1
A      1/1/2012    12
       2/1/2012    14
B      1/1/2012    15
       2/1/2012     8
C      1/1/2012    17
       2/1/2012     9
```

The second dataframe is the following:

```
                   V2
A      1/1/2012    15
       3/1/2012    21
B      1/1/2012    24
       2/1/2012     9
D      1/1/2012     7
       2/1/2012    16
```

and as result I would like to get the following:

```
                   V1   V2
A      1/1/2012    12   15
       2/1/2012    14  N/A
       3/1/2012   N/A   21
B      1/1/2012    15   24
       2/1/2012     8    9
C      1/1/2012    17  N/A
       2/1/2012     9  N/A
D      1/1/2012   N/A    7
       2/1/2012   N/A   16
```

I have tried a few versions using the `pd.merge` and `.join` methods, but nothing seems to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You should be able to use `join`, which joins on the index as default.  Given your desired result, you must use `outer` as the join type.

```
>>> df1.join(df2, how='outer')
            V1  V2
A 1/1/2012  12  15
  2/1/2012  14 NaN
  3/1/2012 NaN  21
B 1/1/2012  15  24
  2/1/2012   8   9
C 1/1/2012  17 NaN
  2/1/2012   9 NaN
D 1/1/2012 NaN   7
  2/1/2012 NaN  16
```

> Signature: _.join(other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)
>   Docstring:
>   Join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key
>   column. Efficiently Join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once by
>   passing a list.

Answer (score 87):

You can do this with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The keyword argument `how='outer'` keeps all indices from both frames, filling in missing indices with `NaN`.  The `left_index` and `right_index` keyword arguments have the merge be done on the indices. If you get all `NaN` in a column after doing a merge, another troubleshooting step is to verify that your indices have the same `dtypes`.

The `merge` code above produces the following output for me:

```
                V1    V2
A 2012-01-01  12.0  15.0
  2012-02-01  14.0   NaN
  2012-03-01   NaN  21.0
B 2012-01-01  15.0  24.0
  2012-02-01   8.0   9.0
C 2012-01-01  17.0   NaN
  2012-02-01   9.0   NaN
D 2012-01-01   NaN   7.0
  2012-02-01   NaN  16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate horizontally as well. Since `concat` matches on index and performs outer join by default, simply passing `axis=1` argument to specify that the concatenation is horizontal suffices.

```py
joined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

An advantage of `concat` over `merge` and `join`<sup>1</sup> is that you can pass a list of dataframes and concatenate many frames in one go with minimal fuss.

```py
joined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df1, df2], axis=1)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It can be done with `join` too but if there are duplicate column names, they have to do be dealt with before the `join` call, whereas with `concat`, it doesn't matter.