# Joining 2 dataframes with different index titles

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files which i want to join together to make a single continuous csv using pandas dataframe. The csv files are shown below
[CSV1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODGnd.png)
[CSV2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBhwQ.png)

[CSV final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFv9k.png)

I tried concat , join, merge as dataframe but none of the methods preserve the "rates" and "cost" as string in the output csv

Comment: Merge does not work?

Are you joining on the index or columns.
This question may be related.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538780/merging-dataframes-on-index-with-pandas

Also, could you add some sample code to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `pd.concat` with `axis` = 0

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('CSV1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV2.csv')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
print(df)

Unnamed: 0    A  B  C
     rates  1  2  1
         2  2  5  6
      cost  9  4  8
         6  2  7  4
```