# Pandas - All I want is a single series value output with not other metadata

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, output

I have 2 dataframes that I have successfully merged together which results in a single desired row of data.

Then I successfully determined the whole value difference between two integer columns.

Now all I want to do is output the integer value result, with no other metadata.

IN:

def answer_four():

```
Top15 = answer_one()
Top15_6th = answer_three()
Top15_6th = Top15_6th.iloc[[5]]

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538780/merging-dataframes-on-index-with-pandas

Top15_6th_ab = pd.merge(
                           Top15_6th[['avgGDP']],
                           Top15[['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']],
                           left_index = True,
                           right_index = True
                       )

Top15_6th_ab['Value_10yr_Change'] = Top15_6th_ab['2015'] - Top15_6th_ab['2006'] 

return Top15_6th_ab['Value_10yr_Change']
```

answer_four()

OUT:

Country
United Kingdom     246702696075
Name: Value_10yr_Change, dtype: float64

All I want in OUT is:

246702696075

I assume I need to add some method/parameters after my return clause, but through much research I have found the answer.

Thanks for your time and assistance in advance!

Matt

Comment: Top15_6th_ab['Value_10yr_Change'][0] 
Can you try adding this [0] at the end ?

Comment: Thanks prog_guy, worked as desired.  I figured is was going to be a simple resolve that I was missing, as no matter how i posed the question in Google or Stackoverflow, I never found the answer.  My noobiness is showing on this one, probably a basic concept I should know.  Well I do now, thanks again!

Comment: Sure, can help to mark my solution as the answer. It will help with my reputation points. Thanks

Comment: Noob to interacting with Stackoverflow too, done, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top15_6th_ab['Value_10yr_Change'][0]